# How to open a URL in webview without prompting for the browser selection in Android Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

Can any one please tell me how to open a URL in default webview. I am using below code but it is not working. It is still prompting to select the intent. This code is working fine in my samsung S2 smartphone. but not in Galaxy tablet.

```
browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                //check for key strings in URL to determine next action.
                int useNativeIntent = 0;
                int bolDone = 0;


                //allow loading of this URL
                if(useNativeIntent == 0){
                    showProgress("Loading..","This may take a moment if you have a slow internet connection.");
                    loadBrowser(url);
                }

                return true;

            }

//loadBrowser
public void loadBrowser(String theUrl){
    if(browser != null){
        try{
            browser.loadUrl(theUrl);
        }catch(Exception je){
            hideProgress();
            showAlert("Error Loading?","There was a problem loading some data. Please check your internet connection then try again.");
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: variable `browser` is an instance of `WebView` rt ?

Comment: yes . It is webview. Honeycomb behavior is different ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly, until and unless you know the activity name of the browser app that you want to trigger, which is not a good idea anyway.

Leave the option to the user, or you could implement your own browser like module inside your app, and take the user directly to your app's browser.

Comment: but the question author already uses the `WebView` rt ? he is trying to load the url inside the webview itself.